# The ( changed ) meaning or classification of words in programming

Tags: nouns, adjectives, programming

I am facing a bit of a dilemma / problem.

I am an amateur programmer ( [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244126/obmerk-kronen) ) , and in programming languages some terms are accepted, known to everyone and frequently used everywhere.

My confusion is  that when I am passing my code in a spell checker, some terms are marked as wrong and / or  need corrections.

Some examples:

`accepted term` = the suggested / correct (alternative)

- `plugin` = plug-in ( plug in )
- `uploader` = up-loader ( up loader )
- `textarea` = text-area ( text area )
- `checkbox` = check-box ( check    box )
- `submenu` = sub-menu ( sub menu )
- `metatag` = meta-tag ( meta    tag )
- `screenshot` = screen-shot ( screen shot )

Now for those of you that have ever experienced basic programming, those terms would be very familiar, but how should I treat those terms when releasing my software ? (Even while writing here, My firefox browser marks all those terms as spell errors. Better yet, the name "`firefox`" itself is marked as an error :-)  )

I must stress that I am not a native speaker and English is not my mother tongue (it is a mere 1 out of 8), But I would still like to know what is the correct way to handle those situations.

I do suspect that some of these terms (like `checkbox` or `plugin`) have become an adjective by themselves and are no longer exclusively used as a noun or as descriptive term for an action.

Comment: This is really off topic IMO. Also, you should not be using a spell-checker on source code. Ever. Use an IDE with syntax highlighting or use Notepad++ (etc etc)

Comment: @horatio Of course you should use a spellchecker on source code! How else will you know if you screwed up the domucentation in the commments?

Comment: @horatio - I am using an IDE , and syntax highlighter has nothing to do with the question. Even NP++ that you yourself mentioned has a built in spell Checker. I believe that either you have never released a software, or you misunderstood the question... How else should one spell check 20,000 different translatable strings ???

Comment: code != localization strings

Comment: Can you state your exact English language question in one sentence at the beginning? The title is not a question. "... how should I treat those terms when releasing my software?" is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Please stop putting spaces around your punctuation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Now , for those of you that ever experienced basic programming , those terms would be very familiar , but how should I treat those terms when releasing my software ?

If the terms are within the code, then don't worry about spellcheck errors. Like you said, these are generally understood terms, and very few programmers care about dictionary levels of correctness in code.

If you're using a term that is not generally understood by non-programmers in the UI or documentation for your program, replace it with something more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to "educate" your spell checker (that is, update its database with common spellings of technical terms), do so.

If you want to "correct" the terms that the spell-checker flags, you probably know that many programming languages do not allow hyphens within variable names, so there's nothing you can do about terms like *plugin* (for which *[plug-in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/plug-in_6)* is the correct form).

As you educate your spell checker, however, it would help to have a good dictionary handy. Note that in the examples you cite, *[uploader](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/upload)*, *[checkbox](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/checkbox)*, and *[screenshot](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/screenshot)* are considered correct as they stand.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting code through a spell-checker?

It may be useful to spell-check your documentation, but any code snippets quoted will be copied verbatim from the programs, and therefore not necessarily standard English (of any variety).

If, on the other hand, you want to check that any displayable messages embedded in your code are spelled correctly, it might be useful to try to structure your modules so that these are declared as constants, or fetched from a text file or database. This way, you only need to spell-check the message file. It will also give you the opportunity to be able to develop alternative language versions of your programs by simply replacing the message file, leaving the functional logic untouched.

Comment: You spell check your code so you don’t look like an unprofessional idiot.  Stop lists for variable names are a completely different matter.

Comment: I did not posted this question to discuss programming methodology, but language . How to treat those strings of language that might have a ( correct ) meaning in a certain context but are grammatically ( or spelling wise ) wrong .

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8786880/509840.

Running your code through a spell check is a little like ironing your underwear. It's an effort that no one will see.

Comment: This is a mistake. You should certainly spellcheck your code.  Othrewies yor cmments lkko lkie txtspk.

Comment: For years I had to use a record that our vendor named "ItemAnlysis".  I cursed them every time I encountered it.

Comment: @ragah9 - what do you mean no one will see ?? how do you recon that UI are made ? by magic ? I have a surprise for you, they are made with CODE . Take a look at this very website here .. how many strings do you think are in the code ?

Comment: They are called "string literals" and are for the express purposes of presentation for the user. It is arguable that "code" is what they are, and I think you might find that they are considered "data." In any event, I think you should take note that everyone has construed your question as misguided. Perhaps you should edit your question slightly to emphasize that you are referring to strings which are presented to a user.

Comment: @tchrist Code <> Comments. /* Comments mispelled wil halve no affect on UI */ On any modern IDE, a misspelled code fragment will have a wavy underline. To use Hellion's example, if I correctly spelled the variable as ItemAnalysis, then IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans, et al. will not compile your code until you knuckle under and misspell it.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen, please dial down the sarcasm. The user sees neither comments nor variable names. The compiler won't let you misspell keywords. The Eclipse plug-in that I described in the answer may help you spell comments and variable names better. While you said, "I am passing my code in a spell checker" apparently you meant "I am passing my string literals through a spell checker." Understanding your question depends on whether you think both `i++;` and `"meta-tag"` are code. (I think the former is code and the latter is not code, but rather a string literal; you call them both code).